# storing time-series data in a database or binary file

Tags: mysql, database

I am storing large amounts of time-series financial market tick data.

Generally, this data is written sequentially (ie - data is timestamped as it comes in, and then written to db).

I need to read the data based on timestamp (only) - ie a general query would be something like "select all data between 1-Jan-2012 and 1-Feb-2012".

**Question:** Am I better off storing this data in a binary file, or a mySQL database, if READ performance is paramount?

It seems to me that the characteristics of the data may be better suited to a file, and my preliminary testing seems to indicate that this is faster (ie, I can read the data back faster).

Answer (score 1):

Your description only talks about the time dimension. But what is/are the other dimension(s)? Probably the different financial instruments (MSFT, IBM, AAPL etc.).

The nature of financial market data usually is that it is received ordered by the time dimension (you get daily updates of hundred thousands of stock prices) but queried by the financial instrument dimension (you query all prices of a single instrument, possibly somewhat restricted by time).

So if you want maximum read performance, you have to make sure that your data isn't stored the way it's received but the way it will be queried, i.e. on the disk, it has to be physically ordered by financial instrument.

I've successfully implemented this in the past in Oracle. There you basically create an index-organized table with the financial instrument identifier and the date as the primary key (the identifier needs to be first). Oracle will then more or less store the data sorted by financial instrument identifier and date. So if you query the stock prices of a single instrument for a given time range, all the required data will be on consecutive disk pages, will already be in the desired order and thus the query will be very fast.

I don't have much experience with MySQL. But as far as I understand it, you can achieve the same with the InnoDB storage engine and clustered indexes:

```
CREATE TABLE prices (
    ticker CHAR(10),
    date DATE,
    close NUMBER(10, 4),
    PRIMARY KEY (ticker, date)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

And please don't use binary files. You'll regret it.

Comment: thanks. Yes you are right, the other dimension would be instrument. How large could this schema get with reasonable performance?